# How to stop RabbitMQ starting on Ubuntu bootup?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ on Ubuntu, but I want to only start it when needed manually, not have it load automatically upon boot.

Comment: Did you use the Ubuntu installer from here? http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `update-rc.d`:

```
update-rc.d -f rabbitmq-server remove
```

Answer (score 17):

With Ubuntu 15.10 (using systemd), I used [systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

```
sudo systemctl disable rabbitmq-server
```